# Why do we say the complete Hallel on Chanuka?

Tags: halacha, chanuka, rosh-chodesh-new-month, passover

On Rosh Chodesh and after the first days of Pesach we say Chatzi Hallel. Why on Chanuka do we say Hallel Shaleim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mishna B'rura says each day is separate from the last because each one commemorates an individual and independent *chag* that each day's *nasi'* made in celebration of his contribution to the dedication of the Mishkan. Similarly we say full *halel* each day of *Sukos* because each day had a separate type of *karban*.

Comment: Could someone add a link to the quoted Mishna B'rura ?

Comment: @WAF: if I'm understanding Mishnah Berurah correctly (http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&pgnum=298), he's saying that we say full Hallel each day because each day there was a new miracle (that the oil kept on burning) - nothing to do with the nesi'im.

Answer (score 2):

As heard from Rabbi David Twersky,
   saying Hallel on Rosh Chodesh was always just a minhag, and there was a desire to show that this was just a minhag so only half-Hallel was said (and some poskim held that a bracha should not be said on Rosh Chodesh for Hallel).

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score -1):

Another answer is that for everyday we say Half Hallel during the Year we say a whole Hallel on Chanukah.That means if you count the Days you say Half Hallel on Yom Tovim they add up to 8 which corresponds to the days of Chanukah.

Comment: How so? Other than Rosh Chodesh (of which there are a lot more than 8 during the year), we say half-Hallel on the last six days of Pesach. Where are the other two?

Comment: Besides for Rosh Chodesh

Comment: Sukkos shmini atzeres

Comment: But on those we say whole Hallel. So what are the eight days of half-Hallel you're referring to?